# Trouble connecting to the internet with direct connection to the modem

Tags: windows, networking, routing, ip, dhcp

I have a windows server that is directly connected to the modem but cannot connect to the internet with the APIPA self-assigned IP address. There's no router/DHCP as that's going to be the servers role on the network. When I try to find the IP address of the modem through `arp -a` it doesn't seem to show up(there's a bunch of 224.*, 239.*, 255.* ip addresses) so I cannot set the default geteway for the modem.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

The way I seen your post is; you expect the broadband modem to be act as a router.

The fact you receive no IP make me think the modem is in bridge mode. While it's not what you want, I strongly suggest to keep the setup that way and to go buy a router to be in between the modem and your server.

Call your ISP to get the IP you need to setup, for the router or the server.

In example the router will allow your server to NOT be multihomed, which can cause a lot of headache in the end.